# Tweet preview using Public API

Tags: twitter

I use [Twitter Public API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public). I allow my users to tweet from my application and I would like to give them final look before publishing. Do you know a way of doing it using only Public API or even without it?

Comment: What do you mean "final look"? It will appear on Twitter exactly as they have typed it.

Comment: As listed on [Twitter Agreement And Policy I.C.3](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/agreement-and-policy):
"If your Service allows users to post Content to Twitter, then, before publishing, show the user exactly what will be published, including whether any geotags will be added to the Content."

Comment: That just means that you must not add any extra data to the user's tweet. If they type in "What a cool app" you are not allowed to automatically add in a hashtag, link, etc.

Comment: The user is adding comment to existing tweet. User writes a comment in input and after hitting 'save' the application adds a url of commented tweet.